# Can you help me with changing row colors using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

I have table `cost` as such :

```
Type    cost    single/married
Cooking   300$    married
Gasoline   400$   married
Nigtlife   600$   single
```

I want to enter a certain income, and check if the cost is greater than the income . iF it is I'm going to flag some certain signal, In my case I'm changing background color to red of the whole row.
I also need to select the rows of married people only, singles are not to be included

This is the jquery code so far:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    var income=('#income').Val();
    $('#cost > tbody  > tr').each(function(){
       $("tr td:contains('married')").each(function(){
          if($(this).find('td').eq(1).text() > income)){
              $(this).css('backgroundColor','red');
          }
        });
    });
});
```

Form:

```
<h2> Insert budget</h2>
<form action="" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="income" id="income">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

But for some reason whenever I click the submit button on my page I get an error..

Comment: hi, what error?

Comment: well, what is the error you get

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

-You forgot `$` before `('#income')`

-You can make use of the parameters of the `.each()` function to interate through the table and match the rows you want.

-If you want to evaluate the `cost` column, you need to remove the dollar sign and parse it as a number

You can try this:

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="income" id="income">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    var income=$('#income').val();
    $('#cost tbody tr').each(function(key,val){
        if(
            $(val).find('td').eq(2).text() == "married" &&
            Number($(val).find('td').eq(1).text().slice(0,-1)) > income
        ) {
            $(val).css('backgroundColor','red');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```